# Executing CMD command remotely

Tags: powershell, cmd

I need to execute some commands remotely on computers and receive back input, to prevent calling every user and remote desktop to use CMD.

**What I need to do:**
Run CMD as admin, and run the two lines below and review the results. (On 30+ computers)

```
cd "c:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus Agent"
nessuscli agent status --local
```

**I tried:**

```
wmic /node:COMPUTERNAME process call create "cmd.exe /c start"
```

It worked on my computer, but I think it opened the command prompt on the other persons computer when I tried this.

```
winrs -r:COMPUTERNAME CMD
```

WINRM apparently isn't enabled and I don't want to enable it if it's not already enabled.

```
$PC = (Read-Host "Enter Computer Name").ToUpper()

    $PC cmd.exe --% /k cd "c:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus Agent" & nessuscli agent status --local


    write-host -f WHITE "Operation Complete."
```

I couldn't figure out how to make it work with a Powershell script in ISE.

I was able to run the below one from Powershell x86 as admin on my computer, but not sure how I would replicate to run it on an external computer.

```
cmd.exe --% /k cd "c:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus Agent"
nessuscli agent status
```

**EDIT**
I created a .bat file and was able to launch it as admin, but it still requires input from the user to accept the cmd runas admin. Then I cannot see the results of the CMD on my end.

```
$PC = (Read-Host "Enter Computer Name").ToUpper()
#Change $xWare to your folder
[string]$RemoteStagingPath = '\\' + $PC + '\C$\Intel'
$xWare = "C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\"
$password= convertto-securestring $passwordTextBox.Text -asplaintext –force
$credential = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userTextBox.Text,$password
$script = "C:\intel\cmd.bat"

#Runs Nessus
        CP $xWare\cmd.bat $RemoteStagingPath
        Start-Process powershell -Credential $credential -ArgumentList "-noprofile -command &{Start-Process $script -verb runas}"

        write-host -f WHITE "Operation Complete."
```

Comment: The first advice I'd ask you to consider is not to waste your time changing to a directory first. You program will run regardless of its current directory, so just use its full path instead. Also there should be no need whatsoever to use the `start` command, which if you were doing so, due to the doublequoted filepath, would require the inclusion of a `title`. Lastly, depending upon your program, and how it returns output, you may not even need to invoke `cmd.exe` directly either. If you do need to, then I'd doubt that you'd require its `/K` option, which would keep that cmd instance open.

Comment: What problem are you actually solving? Your monitoring tool doesn't report status to a server? Or are you saying the agent is broken?

Comment: Use scheduler `shtasks` to connect to every computer and create a `run on demand` task with admin privileges, and have it run the command `"c:\Program Files\Tenable\Nessus Agent\nessuscli.exe" agent status --local`  - then connect again via `SchTasks` and trigger the run on demand task.  If you need to check the output write the output to a text file on the domain share, then read the results of the text files

Comment: So the issue is some clients are not linked, for the clients that are not linked I need to relink them.

Comment: Why not use winrm? Is it just that its not configured?

Comment: I think winrm would be the solution, I think the shtasks would have worked if I spent more time trying to figure it out. I just got word to hold off on relinking all users until next week so I think we'll just leave this at enable winrm, I appreciate all the help.